# Create subset of points cloud from a predefined ones following two conditions

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I'm trying to optimize `algorithm 1` in my following code. First double loop, I calculate points beforehand which will run only once. Then I have the first version of `algorithm 1` which is another double loop with many branches. After that, I presented the optimized version which runs two times faster. The difference between the two versions is that I declared some variables outside the loops. I added `OpenMP` but it seems it doesn't run in parallel. I need your help to optimize the code further, my goal is to run it in real-time on embedded systems such as the `jetson tx2`. The real-time needs to be defined, but for the moment I need to optimize the code as faster as I can.

The context of the algorithm is first I created a set of 3d points named `all_points_cloud_` and then I push back a subset of those points named `point_cloud_to_be_published` to be used later by another program. The points to be chosen are depending on two variables `pixel>0` and `empty_columns==height`.

Here is the full compiled code with the CMakeLists:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>

#include<pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include<pcl/point_types.h>

class Timer
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        m_StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = true;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        m_EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = false;
    }

    double elapsedMicroseconds()
    {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> endTime;

        if(m_bRunning)
        {
            endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
        else
        {
            endTime = m_EndTime;
        }

        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - m_StartTime).count();
    }

    double elapsedSeconds()
    {
        return elapsedMicroseconds() / 1000.0;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_StartTime;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_EndTime;
    bool m_bRunning = false;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    float max_azimuth = 60*M_PI/180;
    float max_range = 1.2;
    float pixel_per_row = max_range/height;
    float max_elevation = 15*M_PI/180;
    float elevation_step = 0.2;
    float pixel_per_col = max_azimuth/width;

    Timer timer;
    timer.start();
    //Points precalculation - This is running one time at the beginning
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr all_points_cloud_ = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr point_cloud_to_be_published = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointXYZI pt;
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i = i + 1)
        {
            for(double k = 0; k < max_elevation; k = k + elevation_step)
            {
                pt.y = pixel_per_row*i*std::cos(k)*std::sin(pixel_per_col*(j-width/2));
                pt.x = pixel_per_row*i*std::cos(k)*std::cos(pixel_per_col*(j-width/2));
                pt.z = pixel_per_row*i*std::sin(k);
                pt.intensity = 0.0;

                all_points_cloud_->points.push_back(pt);
            }
        }
        point_cloud_to_be_published->reserve(all_points_cloud_->size());
    }
    timer.stop();
    std::cout<<timer.elapsedMicroseconds()<<" microseconds"<<std::endl;


    //Algorithm 1
    double time_miliseconds = 0;
    for(int iteration = 0; iteration < 10000; iteration++)
    {
        timer.start();
        int empty_columns = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < height; i = i + 1)
            {
                int pixel = rand()%2;
                if(pixel == 0)
                    empty_columns++;

                for(double k = 0; k < max_elevation; k = k + elevation_step)
                {
                    int pt_cloud_1d_index = j*height*max_elevation/elevation_step+ i*max_elevation/elevation_step + k/elevation_step;
                    if(pixel > 0)
                    {
                        all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].intensity = 1.0;
                        point_cloud_to_be_published->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].x, all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].y, all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].z));
                    }
                    else
                        all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].intensity = 0.0;
                }
                if(empty_columns == height)
                {
                    for(double k = 0; k < max_elevation; k = k + elevation_step)
                    {
                        int pt_cloud_1d_index = j*height*max_elevation/elevation_step + (height-1)*max_elevation/elevation_step + k/elevation_step;
                        point_cloud_to_be_published->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ((all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].x + 0.1), (all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].y + 0.1), (all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].z + 0.1)));
                    }
                }
            }
            empty_columns = 0;
        }
        time_miliseconds = time_miliseconds + timer.elapsedMicroseconds();
    }
    timer.stop();
    std::cout<<time_miliseconds/10000<<" microseconds"<<std::endl;

    point_cloud_to_be_published->clear();

    //Algorithm 1 + optimization
    time_miliseconds = 0;
    for(int iteration = 0; iteration < 10000; iteration++)
    {
        timer.start();
        static int he_cst = height*max_elevation/elevation_step;
        static int e_cst = max_elevation/elevation_step;
        static int last_row_cst = (height-1)*e_cst;
        int empty_columns = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
        {
            int cst0 = j*he_cst;
            for(int i = 0; i < height; i = i + 1)
            {
                int pixel = rand()%2;
                if(pixel == 0)
                    empty_columns++;

                int cst1 = cst0 + i*e_cst;
                for(double k = 0; k < max_elevation; k = k + elevation_step)
                {
                    int pt_cloud_1d_index = cst1 + k/elevation_step;
                    if(pixel > 0)
                    {
                        all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].intensity = 1.0;
                        point_cloud_to_be_published->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].x, all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].y, all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].z));
                    }
                    else
                        all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].intensity = 0.0;
                }
                if(empty_columns == height)
                {
                    int cst2 = cst0 + last_row_cst;
                    for(double k = 0; k < max_elevation; k = k + elevation_step)
                    {
                        int pt_cloud_1d_index = cst2 + k/elevation_step;
                        point_cloud_to_be_published->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ((all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].x + 0.1), (all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].y + 0.1), (all_points_cloud_->points[pt_cloud_1d_index].z + 0.1)));
                    }
                }
            }
            empty_columns = 0;
        }
        time_miliseconds = time_miliseconds + timer.elapsedMicroseconds();
    }
    timer.stop();
    std::cout<<time_miliseconds/10000<<" microseconds"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The CMakelists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(points_cloud_optimization)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(point_cloud source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(point_cloud ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve* ("`algorithm 1`" is not a meaningful _purpose_).  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight Done sir, thank you

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `pt` variable is shared so you have a major race condition. Declare it local in the inner loop. You should as a matter of fact *always* declare variables as local as possible.
2. The `push_back` function is not threadsafe. Create the vector large enough (you know the dimensions) and then insert the elements at the correct index.